# Needs help with superfish menu - background and text color problem

Tags: css

Hi I have a little CSS problem with a Superfish menu, when an active menu is hovered the color: #000000 don't apply, both background and color is white. The inactive menu works as I want.

Example:

Menu 1 (active)
 - Bla 
 - Bla

Menu 1 (active & hover)
 - Blank
 - Bla

pastebin: http://pastebin.com/ziYaZJ3e

```
.ot-menu li li a:focus, .ot-menu li li a:hover, .ot-menu li li a:active {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  border-bottom: none;
  outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: You going to need to pull out relevant sections of code and a test case if you don't want your question to become TL;DR

Answer (score 0):

```
.ot-menu .current_page_item li a, .ot-menu li .current_page_item a {
    background: black;
    border-bottom: none;
    color: white !important;
}
```

The color set here is the reason you are getting white on white. But if disabled the non-hovered active text becomes black on black BG. You need to re-structure your style rules / ordering.

Where possible try to avoid using !important where you can as it can make tracking down styling issues very difficult (speaking from experience, I've produced some really nasty style-sheets lazy-coding with it).